# ¿Como verificar si un Array <any> esta vacio?

Tags: angular, typescript

Tengo un problema para verificar si un Array esta vacio, estoy intentando realizar una consulta en firebase para encontrar la coleccion correcta y cuando los datos enviados son los correctos, esta me devuelve el resultado en un Array:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el resultado cuando la consulta es exitosa y en caso de que no lo sea devuelve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo utilizado es:

```
     obtenerUsuario(nombre): Observable<any> {
            console.log(usuario)
            return this.db.collection('usuario', ref => ref.where('nombre', '==', nombre)).valueChanges();        
  }
```

Esta es la consulta que devuelve un Observable

```
datoArray: any[] = [];    

this.logserv.obtenerUsuario(nombre).subscribe(res =>
          this.datoArray.push(res));
    
console.log(this.datoArray)
```

De esta forma obtengo los datos obtenidos para mostrarlos en la consola.

Lo que necesito es saber como diferenciar de cuando la consulta devuelve datos vacios y cuando no. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre habrá un arreglo dentro de `datoArray`, que puede estar o no vacío así que se puede evaluar usando su propiedad `length`:

```
this.logserv.obtenerUsuario(nombre).subscribe((res) => {
  this.datoArray.push(res);
  // si la longitud del arreglo en la posición 0 es 0 entonces está vacío
  if (!this.datoArray[0].length) {
    // está vacío
  }
});
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. al utilizar [0] ya no puedo utilizar .length y en caso de solo utilizar this.datoArray.length siempre obtengo 0

Comment: Ya vi el problema, la comprobación debe hacerse dentro del subscribe.

Comment: Gracias ahora ya funciona correctamente. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hola compañero lo que puedes hacer es la siguiente validación

```
if (res.length == 0){
console.log("se encuentra vacío el arreglo")
}else {
console.log("no lo esta")
}
```

te aconsejo ponerle un tipo a la respuesta del servicio, en este caso le pones any para no tener problemas a la hora de la implementación

```
this.logserv.obtenerUsuario(nombre).subscribe((res:any) =>
```

así quedaría tu código

```
 datoArray: any[] = [];    
    
    this.logserv.obtenerUsuario(nombre).subscribe((res:any) =>
if (res.length == 0){
    console.log("se encuentra vacío el arreglo")
    }else {
    this.datoArray.push(res));
console.log(this.datoArray);
    }
```

Comment: Gracias, de esta forma tambien funciona